# Adjoin-set for an ordered set representation

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html):

> **Exercise 2.61**
>
> Give an implementation
>   of adjoin-set using the ordered
>   representation. By analogy with
>   element-of-set? show how to take
>   advantage of the ordering to produce a
>   procedure that requires on the average
>   about half as many steps as with the
>   unordered representation.

```
(define (adjoin-set x set)
  (define (rec subset) 
    (cond ((null? subset) (list x))
          ((> x (car subset)) (cons (car subset) (rec (cdr subset))))
          (else (cons x subset))))
  (if (element-of-set? x set)
      set
      (rec set)))
```

Can this be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `element-of-set?` from `adjoin-set` introduces unnecessary redundancy.  One may incorporate this test within the adjoin-set function (in your case, `rec` should be the main body of your function, with an `=` test added):

```
(define (adjoin-set x set)
  (cond
    ((null? set) (cons x set))
    ((= x (car set)) set)
    ((< x (car set)) (cons x set))
    (else (cons (car set) (adjoin-set x (cdr set))))))
```

This function performs fewer steps since it does not call `element-of-set?`.  However, its complexity is still O(n), which is the same as your implementation's complexity, as well as the complexity of `element-of-set?`.